# How to create a gist on github with basic Authentication in C#

Tags: c#, github, github-api, gist

I use C# .net 4.0 and I would like to create a public gist with my username and password (using basic authentication) on github. http://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#basic-authentication

If I use the correct password, I get the response: `The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.`

If I use a wrong password, I get the response: `The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.`

How can I authenticate and post a public gist under my username?

http://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#create-a-gist. the json I try to send:

```
{
    "description": "the description for this gist",
    "public": true,
    "files": {
        "file1.txt": {
            "content": "my new content "
        }
    }
}
```

C# .NET 4.0 code

```
private void button_createGist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String jsonMessage = "{ \"description\": \"the description for this gist\",  \"public\": true,"
                   + "\"files\": {   \"file1.txt\": {"
                   + "\"content\":\"my new content \"  } }}";

        String _url = "https://api.github.com/gists/";

        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(_url)) as HttpWebRequest;

        String userName = "myUserName";
        String userPassword = "pass123";  
        string authInfo = userName + ":" + userPassword;
        authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));

        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/json";
        // req.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: token {0}", oauthToken));
         //req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(username + ":" + password)));
        req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(jsonMessage);
        writer.Write(jsonMessage);
        writer.Close();

        string result = null;
        using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)//Exception here
        {
            StreamReader reader =
                new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think that I have found the error. I will post the solution tomorrow.

Comment: please, could you publish working sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will keep the full example online. The posted example in the question should work if you
change

`String _url = "https://api.github.com/gists/";`

to

`String _url = "https://api.github.com/gists";`

Use `/gists` instead of `/gists/`